# JQueryMobile listview with thumbnails shows only some pictures

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I am working on a simple app, to test the jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap frameworks.
I have a problem with a listview that has some thumbnails in its element.

The problem is that some picture are correctly resized and rendered while others are not.
I can not understand why: the link are right, if I navigate to them from a browser.
Moreover, if i put the same exact link outside the listview, let's say in a `div` element, the images are correctly rendered (and, obviously, not resized).

This is driving me mad!

[image: Some images are not showed]

The code snippets are (relevant HTML and relevant JS):

HTML

```
<div data-role="content">
   <ul id="docList" data-role="listview">
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++)
{
    var toSet = '<li><a href="#"><img class="myListImg" src='+docs[i].field_obj_image_fid+'/><h3>'+docs[i].title+'</h3><p>'+docs[i].field_obj_image_fid+'</p></a></li>';
    $("#docList").append(toSet);
}
$("#docList").listview('refresh');
```

Thanks you for your help,
    Rik

Comment: Could it be the missing quotations around the source for your image? You have the apostrophes correct, but are missing the quotation marks.

Comment: You were right! I have just added the quotations and everything works... I feel a little dumb now! ><
But I wonder why a couple of images were rendered even without the quotations...

Answer (score 0):

**$("PAGE_ID div:jqmData(role=content) ul #docList").empty();**

for(var i=0; i<
h3>'+docs[i].title+'

'+docs[i].field_obj_image_fid+'

';

}

**$("PAGE_ID div:jqmData(role=content) ul #docList").append (toSet);**

$("#docList").listview('refresh');